# knockout 3 level mapping, 3rd level doesnt change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am new to KnockoutJS and I am trying to create a 3-level model binding, for a master-detail ASP.NET MVC view.

here is the screen i am trying to implement this behavior on:

[image] 
I have the following ViewModel design

```
  public class CreateReservationViewModel
{

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public String LogoPath { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string EndTime { get; set; }
    public int TimeSpan { get; set; }
    public int MinPersons { get; set; }
    public int MaxPersons { get; set; }
    public List<ReservationOptionViewModel> ReservationOptions { get; set; }
    public string MessageToClient { get; set; }
    public CreateReservationViewModel()
    {
        ReservationOptions = new List<ReservationOptionViewModel>();
    }
}

 public class ReservationOptionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeDescription { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public List<ValuesViewModel> ReservationOptionValues { get; set; }
    public ReservationOptionViewModel()
    {
        ReservationOptionValues = new List<ValuesViewModel>();
    }
}

public class ValuesViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ValueTitle { get; set; } // this value i cant seem to get to bind user input always defaults to whatever i set it in knockout 
}
```

and here is my .js  and .html  https://jsfiddle.net/camLpdty/

Although I am able to successfully bind the first and second levels, 3rd level binding always picks up default values i.e: [({ Id: 0, ValueTitle: "this is read only and cant change"})] }

[image]

everything else seems to work...

Comment: Does the third level have default values in the initial data load or only when clicking 'Add Option'? At what point are you expecting it to have values other than the default?

Comment: Well your code keeps changing as I'm trying to work through it, but last time I saw the html in your fiddle it looked like the binding context for the Values column is a bit off. data-bind="value: Values.ValueTitle" - Here Values is an array but you're trying to bind a single input box to it. It doesn't know which element's ValueTitle to use so it's probably not bound to anything. You need to use a "foreach" or change how you're displaying that information.

Comment: i really appreciate your help i took the code down to avoid confusing people, but since you tried to replicate it! i put everything back to exactly the state its now. so to answer your questions, the third level has default values when the user clicks 'add option'  and i am expecting it to get the user input when the user adds some text in there and after clicking the 'add option'. 
i have put the fiddle back for your reference https://jsfiddle.net/camLpdty/ thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your jsfiddle it looks like the binding context for the Values column is a bit off. `data-bind="value: Values.ValueTitle"` - Here Values is an array but you're trying to bind a single input box to it. It doesn't know which element's ValueTitle to use so it's probably not bound to anything. You'll need to use a "foreach" or change how you're displaying that information

As a quick test you can try changing that last binding from:

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control input-sm" 
        data-bind="value: ReservationOptionValues.ValueTitle" />
</td>
```

to

```
<td data-bind="foreach: ReservationOptionValues">
    <input class="form-control input-sm" data-bind="value: ValueTitle" />
</td>
```

This will create an input box for every element in the Values array so you probably don't want to leave it like this, but it should highlight the knockout-context problem